# Plotting gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, probability, gamma-distribution, probability-distribution

Am trying to plot a gamma distribution histogram using R

so i have

```
gam(10, 0.5)
```

I have previously calculated mean as

```
10* 0.5 = 5
```

So Am supposed to plot a histoigram of 100 observations with `scale = 10 and shape = 0.5`

So i have tried

```
x <- round(rgamma(100,shape = 0.5,rate = 10),1)
hist(x)
```

and i get

[image]

which is wrong as the mean is supposed to be 5 but my plot  doesnt produce 5

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale` instead of `rate`. So simulate your data as follows:

```
rgamma(100,shape = 0.5,scale = 10)
```

Read the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output from Alex's suggestion:

```
 x <- round(rgamma(100,shape = 0.5,rate = 10),1)
 hist(x)
```

[image]